# Gravatar: different email used in the past that was changed later?

Tags: support, email, profile-picture, gravatar

So I have used different email, (let's call it `A`), when I registered on Stack Overflow. Then I changed an email (let's call it `B`) for Stack Overflow. Then I used `B` email for Gravatar registration, but my profile picture does not appear. It only shows the identicon...

Am I missing something here? Maybe I have not changed my email properly on Stack Overflow? Are there some specific steps I need to do, to make sure it is actually changed (though I log to Stack Overflow with my `B` email)?

Note I log in through a Gmail account if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your profile isn't set to use Gravatar. It's explicitly set to use the Identicon. To use your actual Gravtar image, edit your profile, click on change picture, and then select Gravatar from the options list. Remember to save your profile at the bottom.

Comment: I see, I did not expect that option to appear, because it was not present before I registered on Gravatar. It seems it appears only if finds related Gravatar profile.

Comment: There is no option now. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/profile-picture-uses-old-email

Comment: @Andrius How long does it take?